# How to isolate code cells in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to put together a Jupyter notebook that does NOT discuss the code in order, so I need to repeat earlier pieces of code.  For example, I might have

```
import numpy as np
centroids = np.random.random_sample([20, 2])
print (centroids)
```

as my first code section, and then

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

centroids = np.random.random_sample([20, 2])
print (centroids)

fig = plt.figure()
graph = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
plt.show()
```

as the second block, and so on.  I know that the usual way for a Jupyter notebook is to start at the top of the code and work your way down, but I've already got the commentary written in a particular way and I'm trying not to have to rewrite it.

Is there any way to create the notebook so that the individual code cells are isolated from each other?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `%%python3` magic command in jupyter notebook, at the start of each cell. Here each cell will execute as an **independent** python script. Thus it will isolate each cell(variables in one cell won't be accessible from other cell)

For example in cell[1]

`%%python3
import numpy as np
centroids = np.random.random_sample([10, 2])
print (centroids)`

Edit:

Also take a look at `%notebook` magic.
Reference: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html